# Cleaning a PCB w/ w/ Isopropyl Alcohol - What Type of Deionized Water Should I Use?

Tags: pcb, cleaning

I read a post on this sub-stack from seven years ago, which detailed exactly what I need to do.  I will be soldering some components on a laptop PCB, and I'll be using rosin flux.  Therefore, I'll be cleaning it w/ 99 percent isopropyl alcohol, which apparently, when it dries, leaves a residue behind.  Thus, I'll be using the DI water to remove that residue.  The only thing the post didn't mention was the type of DI water.

I looked elsewhere online, and remarkably, I couldn't find an answer.  I'm assuming that I'll need to use either Type I or Type II DI water, but I thought it wise to inquire.  Does the type make a difference, and is there a specific brand anyone recommends for this type of work?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: Ethanol does not leave residual. For PCB it is not important but to clean connectors  it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to wipe/clean the residue of the isopropyl alcohol. Its residue is a white-like stain, mainly around components. Maybe that is why you cannot find any references.

Many times you might as well see in other products this white stain, like [here](https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/what-are-those-white-stains-on-the-back-of-this-gpu.3639397/), where someone asks what are those white stains:

[image]

And the accepter answer:

> It looks like residue from cleaning more than corrosion so gently
> cleaning with some isopropyl alcohol should remove it, use a coffe
> filter but not a tissue as that can leave fibers in the board. If it
> is only a leftover residue it should not impact the performance of the
> card.
>
> Is it working as expected? Being an older GPU corrosion is possible if
> it was in a humid enviorment for a time but as it is a used card it is
> a case of you pay your money and take your chance.
>
> Make sure though it is DRY after cleaning before you power it up !!!
>
> Hope it works out for you
>
> Cheers

He recommends re-cleaning the board with isopropanol, <s>but there is no need, since the white stains will be created once again.</s>

**EDIT:**
Ok I just read [here](https://www.chemtronics.com/ultimate-guide-to-cleaning-electronics) That the white stain is not a product from isopropanol, but flux residue as you mentioned. I guess you learn things everyday. So yes, try to remove it again with isopropanol.

> White residue is generally a symptom of ineffective PCB cleaning.
> Common conductive flux residues from the soldering process can include
> various unreacted activators, binders, rheology components, and
> saponifiers. Among these are numerous iterations of acids (abietic,
> adipic, succinic among others), highly basic ingredients (amino
> compounds), and even constituents found in “soaps” such as phosphate
> and sulfate ions. When a cleaner does not fully dissolve all the
> constituents, or the cleaner is not allowed to flow off the PCB, the
> remaining solvent can evaporate off and leave behind residue that is
> either white or like water spots.

Answer (score 0):

The type is not important, and you don't need ultra pure lab quality water, any deionized water you can get from nearest store will work just fine.